# Get title color from category custom field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have installed Advanced Custom Fields and created a color custom field for categories.

Now I want to achieve two things:

1- Display the title text of the post in the color selected in the category custom field.
2- Display category name with the background selected in the category custom field.

I'm using GeneratePress theme and hooking the inline css using the Generatepress hooks. Here's the code:

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$color = get_field('color', $term);
?>

<style>
    .wp-block-post-title {
        color: <?php echo $color; ?> !important;
    }
</style>
```

The problem is that $color variable is not populating the color value from the custom field. When I hardcode the color e.g., #000, the code works perfectly fine.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong in the code? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `get_queried_object_id()`? `get_queried_object()` returns a full `WP_Post` object and according to ACF documentation `get_field()` is looking for just an ID.

Comment: Tried using get_queried_object_id() but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/#displaying-fields), it looks like you can provide the term object to get_field(), however I've tended to use either `taxonomy_#termid` or `term_#termid` for example

```
$color = get_term('color', 'category_1234);
```

or

```
$color = get_term('color', 'term_1234);
```

If those down't work, then I'd check:

- That your ACF field name is definitely `color` (and not colour, as I
  would write - being in the UK) and also worth doing a
  `print_r($term);` or `var_dump($term);`
- To make sure you have a `WP_Term` object
- Check `$colour` using print_r or var_dump again, and
  see what you're getting back